# Visualizing ipython on github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to render a `.ipynb` file on github the way `.md` files are rendered? Basically I am asking if it somehow possible to embed the notebook viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub supports [several formats](https://github.com/github/markup#markups) for README-type files, but IPython notebooks aren't listed among them.

If you are trying to do this with [GitHub *Pages*](https://pages.github.com/) (static sites hosted on GitHub), manually [converting your notebooks](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html#converting-notebooks-to-other-formats) to HTML with `nbconvert` might be useful:

```
ipython nbconvert --to html --template full notebook.ipynb
```

This should output an HTML file and a directory containing images and other files.

If you have LaTeX formulas, they should be handled client-side with [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).